# Storing a Single Bit

Tags: storage, bit

My question might seem a little amateur but I can't find an answer online anywhere. A little awhile ago one of the developers of Minecraft talked about how doors are stored in the game ([link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/p9e0f/jon_the_saviour/c3njngt)). He said they are stored using 4 bits. 2 for orientation, 1 for if it's the upper or lower part, and one for if it's open or closed. This got me thinking of how you do it. You see storing a byte makes since because one ASCII character is a byte. However you can't just write some character into a file that's only a bit because characters can't be stored with only one bit, they are stored as a byte. I know a bit is expressed as either a 1 or a 0. However writing a 1 or 0 into a file will give you 4 bytes not a single bit. So how is this done?

Thanks.

Comment: It's done by bitpacking, putting various pieces of information into one single byte of data.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely done by combining different binary flags. In order to be able to give you a clear explanation, you have to understand how numbers are represented bit-wise. Basically, it's just like counting in decimal with the only difference that there are only two numbers available. Down below is an example (decimal numbers 0-16 in their binary representation).

```
Decimal     Binary

0           0
1           1
2           10
3           11
4           100
5           101
6           110
7           111
8           1000
9           1001
10          1010
11          1011
12          1100
13          1101
14          1110
15          1111
16          10000
```

That is exactly how your computer stores numbers.
You'll also have to get a basic undestanding about bit-wise operators.
Let's say you have two rows of 8 bits which look like this:

```
10101010
01011111
```

If you combine those two rows using the bit-wise or operator - "|" - the output's bit x is 1, if either row 1's bit x is 1 or row 2's bit x is 1. So in our case, the result would look like this:

```
11111111
```

The bit-wise and operator (&) checks if both row 1's bit x is 1 and row 2's bit x is 1.
In our case this is the output:

```
00001010
```

The bit-wise xor (exclusive or) operator (^) checks if only one row's bit x is 1.
Our output would look like this:

```
11110101
```

Basically what Minecraft's developers did was they defined a few flags.

```
// this is just an example, not Minecraft's actual code

public static final byte ORIENTATION_SOUTH = 0; // 00000000
public static final byte ORIENTATION_NORTH = 1; // 00000001
public static final byte ORIENTATION_WEST = 2;  // 00000010
public static final byte ORIENTATION_EAST = 3;  // 00000011

public static final byte PART_UPPER = 4;        // 00000100 - third bit is 1
public static final byte PART_LOWER = 0;        // 00000000 - third bit is 0

public static final byte STATE_OPEN = 8;        // 00001000 - fourth bit is 1
public static fianl byte STATE_CLOSED = 0;      // 00000000 - fourth bit is 0
```

So if they were to want a door state where the door's upper part faces west and is open, they would write it like this:

```
byte state = ORIENTATION_WEST | PART_UPPER | STATE_OPEN;
```

Bit-wise, it would look like this:

```
00000010 | (orientation)
00000100 | (part)
00001000   (open or closed)
```

Which would then end up as:

```
00001110 (west, upper part, open)
```

Although only byte's first 4 bits are used, as you said, you cannot just save bits. Most likely the whole byte gets saved.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you cannot do it when all you need is to store a single bit: you must save at least a byte.

However, if you have multiple items with each one taking less than a byte, you can *pack* multiple items together in a single byte.

Using 4-bit doors as an example, suppose that you want to store information about two doors. You need eight bits for that, and that's a single byte. You can save the first door in the lower four bits, and the second door in the upper four bits. When you need to get the state of the first door, mask away the second one by applying `twoDoorsInOneByte & 0x0F` operation: it strips off the higher part of the byte. When you need the second door, shift its bits into position using the shift left: `(twoDoorsInOneByte >> 4) & 0x0F`: it moves the upper four bits into the upper four bits, and clears off the ones in the upper half of the byte in case your value gets sigh-extended.

Finally, in C you have another option: you can use [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). This may be useful when you would like to pack elements of arbitrary length into a few words to save space. Note that this technique should be applied with care, when the savings are relatively high, or the memory is too scarse (e.g. you are writing embedded code for an 8-bit microcontroller).

Answer (score 1):

Define:

```
DOOR_UP = 0x01
DOOR_LEFT = 0x02
DOOR_BIG = 0x04
DOOR_SMALL = 0x08
DOOR_RED = 0x10
DOOR_BLUE = 0x20
DOOR_GREEN = 0x40
```

If you need left, small, green door write

```
def door := DOOR_LEFT or DOOR_SMALL or DOOR_GREEN (Z** or some generic language)
byte door = DOOR_LEFT | DOOR_SMALL | DOOR_GREEN;  (C++)
```

To check is the door green "ask":

```
door & DOOR_GREEN
```

Zero means not green. Non-zero (actually, DOOR_GREEN) means GREEN door

Addition:

you can even pack two numbers from 0-7 in one byte. The same idea is used in ZX Spectrum (1982) to define color of character:

```
Xbbbfff (bbb - background color, fff - foreground color, X - for blink)
```

To set bkg color 5 and fgd on 4 you use:

```
color = 5 << 3 | 4
```

To get background color use:

```
( color >> 3 ) & mask(0x7) -> 5
```

If you making games every nsec is important. Try to avoid usage of bit operations whenever you can :)

Answer (score 0):

Although they say they are using 4 bits I know that they are actually storing the information in a single byte (which is easy to create as a byte is a primitive data type).

I do not believe it is possible to directly store a single bit but I thought you would like to know that although they stated they were using 4 bits, those bits are stored in a byte.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all modern computers are byte addressable, meaning you can only address (point to) a byte of memory and nothing smaller. So in this case they are storing, probably, a byte. To get at the bit they care about they use bit operations to manipulate the byte:

```
const int OPEN_CLOSE_BIT = 1 << 0;
const int UPPER_LOWER_BIT = 1 << 1;

byte doorByte = getByteFromSomewhere();

if (doorByte & UPPER_LOWER_BIT) {
    // the door is in some state
}
```